# Versioning couchdb map-reduce functions

Tags: git, version-control, couchdb, mapreduce

How do I version control my map/reduce functions for CouchDB?  I'd like to be able to check them into git/github so that my teammates can easily apply them to their local test environments.  I know there the replicate features in CouchDB, but I'd like to keep the db views with the source for the project.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it not the case that the views are defined in some high-level language, javascript or other?  In that case you can store them in a regular source file and version them as you would version any source module. The only remaining trick is how to get them from the textfile source and into CouchDB. But this is also easy: Supposing they are Javascript functions, if you have a Javascript engine, you can get the string representation of the functions, JSONify them, and load them into CouchDB dynamically with a PUT to the appropriate URL.

Comment: I was going down this path, but it seems like it is more complex than it needed to be.  Ideally, I would like to just import/export the JS for the view from the file system so I can commit to git.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is one of the (many) couchapp tools. Basically they all map a bunch of js files in various structures to the design doc layout used by CouchDB, and usually provide some simple push/pull mechanisms to get these in and out.

You can then git init in the main folder & be sure you are versioning your uploaded design docs.

There's a pretty good explanation http://mindeavor.com/blog/the-anatomy-of-a-couchapp just ignore the vendor/ discussion for the moment, its not required.

If you're more of a JS/node guy try https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js/ or kanso http://kan.so/ is awesome but it does a lot more; you may find you need more Couch-fu before getting into it. It's excellent however, you can get by just using `kanso push` to start with.

If you just want to get started, use couchapp http://github.com/couchapp/couchapp which is a python tool, probably the original one.

Comment: Thanks for this! Some of your links seem to have died, though. Kanso looks like it should go to https://kanso.app.medicmobile.org/ now and the explanation link could perhaps go to http://web.archive.org/web/20121024014059/http://mindeavor.com/blog/the-anatomy-of-a-couchapp - I tweeted at the author (@mindeavor) to ask if there was a better URL.

Answer (score 1):

We (and I'm sure most teams) do precisely as you've said.  We keep our views, etc., in our source tree and commit to git.  Our app is a node app, so it's particularly simple for us to slurp in the source, and save them to the DB, but this is fairly simple in any language - just come up with a naming scheme, store the JS files in a particular place, and read the files and store the data in the appropriate key structure in the appropriate `_design/document` in your DB.